# Hector Slam Error on Raspberry Pi 4 with ROS Melodic

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm getting an error when I try to run `catkin_make`

```
Base path: /home/pi/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/pi/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/pi/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/pi/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/pi/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/pi/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/pi/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/pi/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/melodic
-- This workspace overlays: /home/pi/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/melodic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found suitable version "2.7.16", minimum required is "2") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python2
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/pi/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Forcing gtest/gmock from source, though one was otherwise available.
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found version "2.7.16") 
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.23
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 14 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - hector_slam (metapackage)
-- ~~  - hector_slam_launch
-- ~~  - hector_map_tools
-- ~~  - hector_nav_msgs
-- ~~  - hector_geotiff
-- ~~  - hector_geotiff_plugins
-- ~~  - hector_marker_drawing
-- ~~  - hector_compressed_map_transport
-- ~~  - rplidar_ros
-- ~~  - hector_imu_attitude_to_tf
-- ~~  - hector_imu_tools
-- ~~  - hector_map_server
-- ~~  - hector_trajectory_server
-- ~~  - hector_mapping
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'hector_slam'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_slam)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_slam_launch'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_slam_launch)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_map_tools'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_map_tools)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'Eigen' but neither 'Eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor
  'Eigen_LIBRARIES' is defined.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  hector_slam/hector_map_tools/CMakeLists.txt:51 (catkin_package)


-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_nav_msgs'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_nav_msgs)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- hector_nav_msgs: 0 messages, 5 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_geotiff'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_geotiff)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
qmake: could not find a Qt installation of ''
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1313 (message):
  Found unsuitable Qt version "" from NOTFOUND, this code requires Qt 4.x
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  hector_slam/hector_geotiff/CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [Makefile:698: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362429/hello,-i%27m-trying-to-run-hector-slam-on-a-raspberry-pi-4.-i-installed-ros-melodic-and-already-copied-the-hector-folder-to-my-src-work-space.-i%27m-getting-an-error-when-i-try-to-run-catkin_make./) by [MannyR](https://answers.ros.org/users/60177/mannyr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Go to the folder */home/pi/catkin_ws* and run `catkin_make`. Please ensure that you run `source /opt/ros/<ros_distro>/setup.sh`.

---

Originally posted by [wiyogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/60646/wiyogo/) with karma: 44 on 2020-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MannyR](https://answers.ros.org/users/60177/mannyr/) on 2020-10-15**:
Thank you for your help. I was actually able to get this to run when I installed Qt.